# Returning an average of integers only at the list where a string is searched inside a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I'm a beginner with Python.
Say I have a list of lists in python

```
    list1 = [['id1','Jane','Doe',100,75,100],['id2','John','Snow',90,87,92],['id3','Peter','Pan',79,81,83]]
```

How can I search the list of lists for say 'id2' and print a list with only the integers in its list?

This is what I tried

```
    import numbers
    def list_search(lister,index):
        for i in lister:
            for j in i:
                if j == index:
                    [x for x in i if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]
        print("Not found: ",index)
```

Here is the Test for my function

```
    list_search(list1,'id2')
```

I was expecting
[90,87,92]
but I got
Not found: id2

Comment: You never print nor store nor return the list you make when `j == index`, and you always print "Not found" at the end of the function

Comment: This line doesn't do anything `[x for x in i if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]`. You should either print it, or return it.

Answer (score 1):

This solution stops looping when `index` is found.

Returns `None` if `index` has not been found.

Uses a [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)  to easily create a list.

No need to import `Number` just test if it's an integer.

A small optimization consists to look for integers starting from the 2nd row (`item[:1]`) as we know that the first row is the index.

You could even replace 1 by 3 here if you assume that rows 2 and 3 (Jane, Doe) are always string.

```py
def list_search(lister, index):
    for item in lister:
        if item[0] == index:
            return [x for x in item[1:] if isinstance(x, int)]
    return None
```

That's for the first part that provides you with the integers.
Compute the average given the list is the easiest part.

```py
numbers = list_search(list1, "id2")
print(sum(numbers)/len(numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't do anything:

```
[x for x in i if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]
```

You should either print it, or return it. Plus your function will always shows the message `Not found` so your code should be like this:

```
import numbers

list1 = [['id1','Jane','Doe',100,75,100],['id2','John','Snow',90,87,92],['id3','Peter','Pan',79,81,83]]
def list_search(lister,index):
    for i in lister:
        for j in i:
            if j == index:
                return [x for x in i if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]
    print("Not found: ",index)
      
my_list = list_search(list1,'id2')

print(my_list)
# print average
print( sum(my_list) / len(my_list))
```

Output:

```
[90, 87, 92]
89.66666666666667
```

Answer (score 0):

One method using **Try except**

```
list1 = [['id1','Jane','Doe',100,75,100],['id2','John','Snow',90,87,92],['id3','Peter','Pan',79,81,83]]
def list_search(list_of_list,index):
    result=[]
    for lis in list_of_list:
        if lis[0]==index:
            for check in lis:
                try:
                    result.append(int(check))
                except ValueError:
                    continue
    return sum(result)/len(result) if result else 0
print(list_search(list1,"id2"))
```

**Output:-**

```
207.6666666
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the function that you can write. First look all the first elements and if the first element is equal to what you want then check for integers and append them to the result list. Finally return the result list.

```
 def func(a, activatedString):
    result = []
    for i in a:
        if i[0] == activatedString:
            for j in i:
                if isinstance(i, int):
                    result.append(j)

    return result
```

But if you want more short way you can do this:

```
def func(list1, activatedString):
    return [i for i in [a  for a in list1 if a[0] == activatedString][0]  if isinstance(i, int)]

print(func(list1, "id2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with getting only `integers` list:

```
list1 = [['id1','Jane','Doe',100,75,100],['id2','John','Snow',90,87,92],['id3','Peter','Pan',79,81,83]]

temp_integers = [list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), list1[i])) for i in range(len(list1))]
```

Output:

```
>>> temp_integers
... [[100, 75, 100], [90, 87, 92], [79, 81, 83]]
```

Then we add a list of their respective `means`:

```
temp_means=[np.mean(x) for x in temp_integers]
```

Output:

```
>>> temp_means
... [91.66666666666667, 89.66666666666667, 81.0]
```

Then print corresponding integers to `id2` and their `mean` :

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if 'id2' in list1[i]:
        print(temp_integers[i])
        print(temp_means[i])
```

**Put it all in one function**

```
def list_search(lister,index):
    temp_integers = [list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), lister[i])) for i in range(len(lister))]
    temp_means=[np.mean(x) for x in temp_integers]
    
    if all(index not in y for y in lister):
        print("Not found: ",index)
    else:
        for i in range(len(lister)):
            if index in lister[i]:
                print(temp_integers[i])
                print(temp_means[i])
```

**Output**

```
>>> list_search(list1,'id2')
... [90, 87, 92]
... 89.66666666666667
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension for this:

```
list1 = [['id1','Jane','Doe',100,75,100],['id2','John','Snow',90,87,92],['id3','Peter','Pan',79,81,83]]

def list_search(lister, index):
    return [j for i in lister for j in i if isinstance(j, int) and i[0] == index]

results = list_search(list1,'id2')
print(results)

average = sum(results)/len(results)
print(average)

# Output:
# [90, 87, 92]
# 89.66666666666667
```